# Can I check if a local query scope has been applied in Laravel's Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I use local query scopes in a model to add a few sub queries to aggregate some values. These are then displayed in my Blade templates and used as conditionals to show certain parts of the UI.

This looks something like this (truncated and renamed for brevity)

```php
public function scopeWithFilterData(Builder $query)
{
    $query->addSelect(['sub_query_aggregate'] => ...
}
```

I also have a scope to use these aggregated values to filter the models. I check if the sub query has been added through the scope and otherwise add it to make the sub query aggregates available.

```php
public function scopeFilterData(Builder $query)
{
    $query->when($this->hasFilterDataScope($query), function ($query) {
            $query-> scopeWithFilterData();
        })
        ->havingRaw('sub_query_aggregate IS NULL');
}
```

I have however not found any nice way to check if the local scope has been applied already so the hasFilterDataScope method checks if the aggregate name is present in the Query Builder objects columns property.

```php
private function hasNeedsAttentionScope(Builder $query)
{
    $columns = $query->getQuery()->columns;

    return is_null($columns)
           || count(preg_grep('/sub_query_aggregate/', $columns)) === 0;
}
```

It gets the job done but doesn't feel very Laravel-esque. Is there a better and/or cleaner way to do it?

Comment: There is no magic solution here. You need to manually track which scopes have been applied. e.g. `$appliedLocalScopes = []`. Laravel does not do this for you.

Comment: as said it isn't keeping track of that informaiton, when a scope is called it is ran and applied like you added those constraints directly yourself. the scopes are applied when called, they are not accumulated and then later applied.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you for confirming it.